# Windows: keyboard shortcut to expand table columns

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

In windows, I can use <kbd>tab</kbd>/<kbd>space</kbd>/arrow keys to navigate most menus. I can even select and sort by table columns, but is there a way for me to expand a column using just the keyboard? Example:

[image]

(In this menu, resource monitor, I am luckily able to remove some columns from the view to expand the others.)

Is there a way I could expand that last column to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such keyboard shortcut, and in general every product has its own rules.

There is a vague universal convention that a double-click on a column separator
will resize the previous column to autofit to its contents (not including the
column title), but this is not guaranteed to work for every product.